# Compare paragraph word by word

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to compare line in a paragraph line by line and word by word but I feel like this is not the most efficient way can you help me out please. 
If there is a difference I want to return both words.

```
file_1 = open("file1.txt").readlines()
file_2 = open("file2.txt").readlines()


if file_1 == file_2:
    print("Same")
if file_1[0] != file_2 [0]:
    listone = file_1[0].split()
    listtwo = file_2[0].split()
    if listone[0] == listtwo[0] and listone[1] == listtwo[1]:
        pass
    elif listone[0] != listtwo[0] and listone[1] == listtwo[1]:
        print('line 1:\n', listone[0]+"\n", listtwo[0])
    elif listone[0] == listtwo[0] and listone[1] != listtwo[1]:
        print('line 1:\n', listone[1]+"\n", listtwo[1])
```

Edit: By efficient I mean going through an entire paragraph without righting every single line.

Comment: What do you mean efficient? This looks efficient to me.

Comment: But it will only be useful for a limited number of lines

Comment: Not entirely sure what exactly is the goal... as for instance `"a b" == "a  b"` is `False`, but `"a b".split() == "a  b".split()` is `True` (so really a bit apples and oranges). But generally it might be helpful to check out https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use a main for loop. This is some explanation code.

```
file1 = open("file1.txt", r).readlines()
file2 = open("file2.txt", r).readlines()
for i in range(0, len(biggest_file)):
    if file[i] == file[i]:
        print("The text on line:{} is the same in both files".format(i))
    else:
        print("The text on line:{} is not the same in both files".format(i))
```

Just note this isn't working code this is just how the system should work.